# the paired samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

Trace metals in drinking water affect the flavor of the water, and unusually
high concentration can pose a health hazard. The following Table shows trace-metal concentrations (zinc, in mg/L) for both surface water and bottom water at six different river locations. Our aim is to see if surface water concentration (x) is predictive of bottom water concentration(y).

```
Location Bottom Surface 
1    0.430  0.415 
2    0.266  0.238 
3    0.567  0.390 
4    0.531  0.410 
5    0.707  0.605 
6    0.716  0.609
```

a)  Draw a scatter diagram to show a possible association between the concentrations and check to see if a linear model is justified.

b)  Test to see if the two concentrations are independent; state your hypotheses and choice of test size.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Routine questions like this are usually tagged with [tag:self-study] and are treated a little differently from other questions (consult our [help] for details). In particular, we ask that you provide information about your efforts to solve your problem so that we can focus on providing advice to get you unstuck. Please edit your question accordingly.